# Pyspark: Converting a sample to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I trying to extract a sample from a dataframe (`df_spark`) with 100 million rows and converting it to a pandas dataframe using the below code:

```
df = df_spark.sample(withReplacement = False, fraction = 0.05, seed = 11).collect().toPandas()
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'toPandas'
```

I also tried to convert it to rdd and then to pandas and got the same error.

I'm wondering to know once I have the sample list what is the correct method to convert it to a pandas dataframe or a spark dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call `collect()` here. The `sample()` function returns a DataFrame object and the code can be as simple as:

```
df = df_spark.sample(withReplacement = False, fraction = 0.05, seed = 11).toPandas()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue first converting the sample to rdd, then to `spark.DataFrame` and last converting to `Pandas` as code below:

```
df = (df_spark.sample(withReplacement = False, fraction = 0.05, seed = 11)
              .rdd
              .toDF()
              .toPandas())
```